# How do I set method tearDown() in yii with phpunit?

Tags: testing, yii, phpunit, selenium-rc

I wrote a class registration and test for it.

```
$this->open('/');

    if($this->isTextPresent('logout'))
        $this->clickAndWait('link=logout');
    $this->clickAndWait('link=reg');
    $this->assertElementPresent('id=user-reg-form');                
    $this->type('name=User[login]','root111');
    $this->click("//input[@value='Submit']");
    $this->isTextPresent('cannot be blank.');
    $this->type('name=User[pswd]','ll111');
    $this->click("//input[@value='Submit']");
    $this->isTextPresent('cannot be blank.');    
    $this->type('name=User[email]','1a1111@gmail.com');
    $this->click("//input[@value='Submit']");
    $this->waitForTextPresent('logout');
    $this->clickAndWait('link=logout');
    $this->waitForTextPresent('reg');
    $this->clickAndWait('link=reg');
```

And set tearDown() in WebTestCase.php to remove a new record.

```
  //delete test user record
  $exe = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
  $exe->delete('{{user}}', 'id > :id', array(':id'=>5));
  $exe->execute();
```

Tests are performed as needed, but record isn't removed. Why? How do I fix this bug? I try using terDownAfterClass(), but result is the same.

Comment: Just a heads up, according to the [API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#delete-detail) `delete()` creates and executes a delete SQL statement, so `$exe->execute()` is unnecessary.

Comment: without `$exe->execute()` don't work too.(

Comment: Please verify that the `tearDown` method is actually executed or not. If it's not executed you don't need to wonder. If it's executed, verify if that delete command actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to another way. For example find model by attributes (you know their) and delete it.

```
User::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array(
    'email' => '1a1111@gmail.com',
));
```